# Is there an easy way to attach category tags to an image file regardless of file type?

Tags: image, metadata

I want to organize some of my image collections and my initial thought was to attach tags to the metadata, but I know very little about how image metadata works.

Is it completely different for each file format?

Is there an easy way to attach category tags to an image file programatically and regardless of file type?

Is there some primer on image metadata somewhere I could read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add metadata to a media file in [XMP format](https://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/overview.html). It was developed by Adobe, but is becoming quite standard. Look at the [Wikipedia page on XMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) for libraries.